# Why is this rotated text outside of the right arrow image?

Tags: html, css

It's odd, I apply a style to it but it gets applied to SHIFT at times. What is the solution to making the word GROW move to the left of right arrow? Its supposed to be on the inside.

I tried placing the text before the arrow img but it just breaks and disappears. I also tried taking shift and grow out of the a tag completely and I used transform translate but the position of it would not stay put.

```
     <!--ARROW AND TEXT ISSUE -->
          <a class="slidenext" onclick="nextSlide();">
             <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GASeP9Y.png" class="arrow_icon" />
               <div class="grow">
                GROW
               </div>
          </a>

          <a class="slideprev" onclick="prevSlide();">
             <img src="https://i.imgur.com/WLkS6Jk.png" class="arrow_icon" />
            <div class="shift">
                SHIFT
            </div>
          </a>
```

CSS

```
.grow {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(50%, 0%);
  }

  .shift {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-60%, 0%);
  }
  .shift,
  .grow {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #aeaeae;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 15px;
  }
.slidenext {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 250px;
  }

  .slideprev {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 250px;
  }
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/ninabor/pen/eYpGYeM?editors=1100)

Comment: yuou need this arrow to right side of GROW, Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The small thing you can do here,, is use of Flexbox

I have corrected [your code here](https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/yLYPzme), just have a look if this is what you need.

```
 .slidenext {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 250px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

and remove translate property from text of grow and shift.

important thing to note here, if you will move your GROW text a step up, I mean before arrow in your HTML, then you do not need this.

```
 flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

if you want to learn FLEXBOX then very easy and fun way to learn flexbox is [flexbox froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/).

Comment: Atul i will paypal something if you want but I have another issue, how do i get the titleholder to move to the left and when shrinking browser its not supposed to move to the right. this was my inspiration : https://imgur.com/a/xvt7xUm. i want it to stay below her finger when resizing

Comment: It's easy, I will try to help you, but first thing first, if this helped you, don't forget to mark it as the right answer

Comment: yea, now we can talk what else you want?

Comment: Oh! i just wanted the titleholder contents to flow with the page and stay under her finger like imgur.com/a/xvt7xUm. When i resize the broswer the titleholder contents(irregular and button) position moves to the right too much and ruins the look.

Comment: I have updated the code as per your need, check it, Enjoy